# Создание учета рабочего времени (Android)

Tags: android, база-данных, библиотеки, таблицы

есть необходимость и желание создать апп на Java/Kotlin под андроид, обучаюсь не так давно, главный вопрос какой либой пользоваться, чтобы добавить в активити календарь в форме сетки, с дальнейшим внесением туда инфы по тапу на день/ячейку? Идея состоит в том чтобы сделать окно логина с авторизацией пользователей, хранением их инфы например на фаербазе, и распределением например на работяг и директора которые смогут просматривать инфу работяг. Нуждаюсь в конструктивной критеке и либах на которые стоит обратить внимание, что почитать.

Answer (score 0):

Это делается с помощью calendarview.

Если надо библиотека то это то что нужно:
https://github.com/kizitonwose/CalendarView